# How to use node.js to implement multipart/form-data in openapi3's yaml file?

Tags: node.js, openapi

I'm setting up a new server and my goal is to implement multipart/form-data in OpenApi3.0's yaml file. I encounter "should NOT have additional properties (consume)" error in Node.js and wanna know how to fix this error or how to implement multipart/form-data in OpenApi3.0's yaml file?

This is my OpenApi3.0's yaml file to implement this goal, it will report the error I mentioned above.

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: myapp
  description: My cool app
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /api/v1/user
tags:
- name: User
  description: User Operations
paths:
  /onboarding/signature:
    post:
      tags:
      - User
      description: Onboarding Upload Signature API - with parameters user's email and image file
      requestBody:
        description: Request Body {email, image}
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/onboardingSignature'
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK 
        201:
          description: Created
        400: 
          description: Bad Request
        500:
          description: Internal Server Error
components:
  schemas:
    onboardingSignature:
      description: Onboarding Signature File
      type: object
      properties:
        email: 
          type: string
        image:
          format: binary
```

I expect the implementation of uploading file in Swagger use multipart/form-data format.

Comment: 1) `type: formData` (on the last line) is not a valid type, I assume you need `type: string` + `format: binary`. Also, the `image` and `file` properties must be direct properties of the `onboardingSignature` schema rather than nested properties. (See the [Multipart Requests](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/) guide.) 2) How are you implementing this in Node.js? Did you use a specific code generator to generate server code from this spec? And/or do you use a specific Node.js library/framework?

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT grateful for your help, the framework I used is "express-no-stress". I have tried your suggestion and modified my yaml code, the new version is as the code in the question I newly modified. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Now I use `email: type: string` and `image: type: binary`, the error received from postman is "schema is invalid: data.properties['image'].type should be equal to one of the allowed values, data.properties['image'].type should be array, data.properties['image'].type should match some schema in anyOf". I wanna know how to fix and make it work?

Comment: There's no `type: binary`, use `type: string` + `format: binary` instead.

Comment: @Helen Dear Helen, when I modified the yaml code as the question I newly modified, or use `image:   type: string    format: binary`. The error received from postman is "There is no signature file", it because I write the condition in my controller code `if(!req.file)`, it means it can not feel the file I input, how to fix it?